# How do I animate gif inside CollectionViewController.. (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, gif

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    [_keyboard.collectionView registerClass:[NibCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];


    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    NibCell *cell = [self.keyboard.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView * rampageGifImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];


    [rampageGifImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.gif",[rampageGif objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];


    [cell.layer setCornerRadius:4];

    [cell addSubview:rampageGifImage];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you cannot have a gif on a native view. use webView for this or if you really want to show it use a library that breaks the images and reanimates it. https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gif Image by Adding [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) from Github in your project.

Try like this,

```
#import "UIImage+GIF.h"

_imageViewAnimatedGif.image= [UIImage sd_animatedGIFNamed:@"YOURGIF_IMAGE"];
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Visit this link for better understanding : https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImage%2BGIF.m

Comment: Anyway, I have used FLAnimatedImage from github.. but the problem is, App is crashing becuz of excess amount of memory usage ...Can you help me with this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Try it. It is small category that could loads animated GIF. Also, jpg, png, etc..](https://github.com/wugi88/UIImageGif)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "UIImage+Gif.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView2;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Usage 1 : gifWidthData
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"f1" withExtension:@"gif"]];

    self.imageView1.image = [UIImage gifWithData:data];

    // Usage 2 : gifWidthURL
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"f2" withExtension:@"gif"];
    self.imageView2.image = [UIImage gifWithURL:url];
}
```